# Using CALL statement

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to learn vb.net as part of visusl studio 15.
I have always used the "Call" statement to call sub routines.  I like it because it is easier to read my code at a later date when I may not remember the names of every sub or function I created.
The question is, does this practice add any additional overhead.  I realize I must use brackets for passing variables, but just want to know if this practice will impact the final size, or memory requirements in the final compiled program.

Comment: No extra overhead, its just an archaic convention not needed for many years now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is pros and cons of calling procedures in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848086/what-is-pros-and-cons-of-calling-procedures-in-vb-net)

Comment: `I like it because it is easier to read my code at a later date when I may not remember the names of every sub or function I created.` - In what way does the `Call` keyword help you remember that??

Comment: `I realize I must use brackets for passing variables` - You always use brackets when you pass parameters, with _and_ without the `Call` keyword. `Call MyMethod(a, b, c)` is equal to `MyMethod(a, b, c)`.

Comment: @VisualVincent - That was not true for VB6.  In VB6, if you did not use the `Call` keyword, you had to pass parameters without the parentheses when calling a `Sub`.  When calling a `Function` you always used parentheses.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway : Interesting... I haven't used VB6 in many, many years. Though this isn't VB6, now is it? :)

Answer (score 2):

The `Call` keyword exists to make it easier to port older VB6-era code forward to VB.Net, but otherwise should not be used.